# JavaScript. Extract values from associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I get the values from this associative array in JavaScript?

I just need the email addresses and not the labels.

```
(
  {
    office = ("my@email.com");
    home = ("ahome@anotheremail.com");
    work = ("nothing@email.com");
  },
  {
    home = ("test@test.se");
  }
)
```

**UPDATE**: Prefered output in JSON would be:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "email": "my@email.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "ahome@anotheremail.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "nothing@email.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "test@test.se"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 4):

What you probably meant to do is:

```
var x = [{
 office: ("my@email.com"),
 home: ("ahome@anotheremail.com"),
 work: ("nothing@email.com")
},
{
 home: ("test@test.se")
}]
```

and:

```
for(var j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
{
    for(var anItem in x[j])
    {
        console.log(x[j][anItem])
    }
}
```

// EDIT:
however, [it's not the best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) to use for … in.

Maybe you could change your data structure to:

```
var x = [[{
        value: "my@email.com",
        type: "office"
    },
    {
        value: "ahome@anotheremail.com",
        type: "home"
    },
    {
        value: "nothing@email.com",
        type: "work"
    }],
    [{
        value: "test@test.se",
        type: "home"
    }]];
```

and iterate over using:

```
for( var i = 0, xlength = x.length; i < xlength; i++ )
{
    for( var j=0, ylength = x[i].length; j < ylength; j++ )
    {
        console.log(x[i][j].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the data structure. I am developing an iPhone application in Appcelerator and this is what I get when I request information from the build in addressbook. They best would be if I could get the final output (addresses only) in JSON format. Is this possible?

Comment: The current out put is now: [["my@email.com"],["ahome@anotheremail.com"],["nothing@email.com"],["test@test.se"]] in JSON. I would be cool if this could be: {"data": [{"email": "my@email.com"},{"email": "ahome@anotheremail.com"},{"email": "nothing@email.com"},{"email": "test@test.se"}]}. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner:

```
console.log(Object.keys(assoc).map(k => assoc[k]));
```

where `assoc` is your associative array.

#### Edit

I have a better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62305765/11714860).

Answer (score 1):

You can 'foreach' over the object to get it's properties:

```
for(var j = 0; j < mySet.length; j++)
{
    for(var propName in mySet[j])
    {
        var emailAddress = mySet[j][propName];
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error with the above code (myObj) changed it to mySet and made an alert of emailAddress but each alert was empty. What is wrong?

Comment: This time it worked perfectly! Thanks! Is it possible to rename all labels to the same name for example the word email instead of work?

Comment: You can translate those values into another object of your choosing.

Comment: he current out put is now: [["my@email.com"],["ahome@anotheremail.com"],["nothing@email.com"],["test@test.s­e"]] in JSON. I would be cool if this could be: {"data": [{"email": "my@email.com"},{"email": "ahome@anotheremail.com"},{"email": "nothing@email.com"},{"email": "test@test.se"}]}. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're looking for [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

Comment: Please give the specific answer that refer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Answer for edited question:

```
var ret = {data: []};

for(var j = 0; j < x.length; j++)
{
    for(var anItem in x[j])
    {
        ret.data.push({
            email: x[j][anItem]
        });
    }
}

console.log(ret);
```

The result is kept in `ret`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it your input in JSON format? Because if so, it's the wrong syntax. However

```
let _in = [
 {
   office : "my@email.com",
   home : "ahome@anotheremail.com",
   work : "nothing@email.com",
 },
 {
   home : "test@test.se"
 }
]

let _out = []
_in.forEach( record => {  
   _out =  _out.concat(Object.values(record).map(x => new Object({email : x})))
})

console.log(_out)
```

for each record I extracted values and "packed" into an object with the "email" attrbiute, then I merged all those arrays obtained from the original array of records